# What is the best way to update a model object through a model-controller (API wrapper) only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have an iOS application with several model classes and a wrapper-class for API calls to a web-service that I am using as a model controller.

Here is an example of a simple Model object.

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

+ (Person *)personWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName;

@end
```

To retrieve this object from the web service I have a model-controller in which I have implemented the following methods.

```
- (NSArray *)allPeople;
- (void)addPerson:(Person *)newPerson;
- (void)deletePerson:(Person *)newPerson;
```

This is great at the moment. However, I am now adding editing capability which I would also like to wrap in the model controller but am unsure as to the best way to structure this. Obviously, the easiest way to update a Person object would be to just access the properties on an object directly. But at the moment the model object does not know anything about the web service and I want to keep it that way. I could add a method to the model controller such as

```
- (void)updatePerson:(Person *)person withFirstName:(NSString *)newFirstName
```

or something similar and make the properties on the Person object readonly but this does not seem very intuitive. Still, I cannot think of any other way to do this without adding controller code into the model class. Does this seem like the appropriate way to handle this situation? Are there any other alternatives?

**Update**
I do not know what I was thinking above, but I would be unable to make the properties on the model objects readonly since the Model Controller class would need to access and update those properties somehow. This means that it would be possible to update the person object directly bypassing the api wrapper which would be troublesome. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Person properties should not be readonly.
Your API should have an updatePerson method with this signature:

```
- (void)updatePerson:(Person*)person;
```

Your person should have some sort of a unique id, so it can be identified when you're trying to update it.
When you need to update a person you will do something like this:

```
// first - create the object
Person *p = [[Person personWithFirstName:@"John" lastName:@"Appleseed"];
[apiObject addPerson:p];
// then you can update
p.fisrtName = @"Kate";
[apiObject updatePerson:p];
```